# レンタルサーバでweinreを使える？

Tags: cordova

お世話になっております。
現在デバッグツールとして`weinre`を使用しているのですが
ローカル環境で`weinre`を使用すると同一LAN内でないと使えないので、
外からでも`さくらインターネット`などの**root権限の無い**レンタルサーバ上で`weinre`が使えないかと考えております。
`weinre`を見ている感じですと、`weinre`＞`web`を公開しているので
`web`ディレクトリを設置すれば使用できないかと思いましたがダメでした……。

なにか方法はないでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

weinreは別のブラウザからデバッグコンソールを使えるようにするツールですが、そのようなことを実現するにはデバッグする側・される側のブラウザが相互に通信できなければなりません。仮に直接ブラウザ間で通信するとなると、どちらかをサーバーとして通信を受け付けられるようにしなければなりませんが、ブラウザにそのような機能はありません（最近また変わってきてはいますが）。

そのためweinreは次のような構成を取っています。

- デバッグする側のブラウザで動かすJavascript
- デバッグされる側のブラウザで動かすJavascript
- **両者の間の通信を仲介する、Node.jsベースのサーバープログラム**

root権限はなくても構いませんが、**Node.jsでサーバーを動かせる**環境でないといけないので、よくある「Perl・PHP・Rubyが動きます！」みたいなレンタルサーバーでは厳しいかと思います。動かせる環境の例としては・・・Herokuとか。時々しか使わないなら無料プランで足りるかもしれません。

例 https://github.com/pmuellr/weinre-heroku

また、厳密には「同一LAN内でないと使えない」という制約はありません。`--boundHost` オプションを正しく設定し、外部からサーバーにアクセスできるようルーターなどの設定を行えば、自宅のPCで動かしたweinreサーバーを外から使うことも可能です。

なお、weinreのサーバーはあまりセキュリティについて考慮されておらず、SSLを使っていないのはもちろん、アクセス制限の機能も持っていません。**weinreサーバーにアクセスできる人は誰でも**、デバッグ対象のブラウザ上で任意のスクリプトを実行できる、という点には注意してくださいね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。レンタルサーバにNode.jsを設定する記事を見つけたので何とかなるかもしれません。該当ページへはIPで弾く予定ですが気をつけてみます。

Comment: @Myaku シェルログインの存在を忘れていました、なるほど確かに。ただ禁止事項に「daemonとしてサーバーに常駐するプログラムの実行」という項目があるのが気にはなりますが・・・。 http://www.sakura.ne.jp/terms.html